# Run Radiant CMS site on Cloud9 - Wrong Port?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cloud9-ide

I usually run my rails installation on Cloud9 by typing the following line into my command line: rails server -b $IP -p $PORT

And it launches my environment into a browser. However I've just installed the Radiant CMS, and doing this no longer works. Instead, I'm instructed to do the below:

> Your Radiant application is ready to use. Run `script/server -e
>   production` to start the server. Your site will then be running at
>   http://localhost:3000

So I run that line (script/server -e production) in my terminal, and I receive the following (instead of getting my environment):

> You may be using the wrong PORT & IP for your server application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still specify the port and IP by using the command:

`script/server -e production -b $IP -p $PORT`

HTH